# X-Editable check dynamically checked options into checklist

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

Hy guys,

I'm using the X-Editable plugin for table inline editing (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/). I have an answer with the **checklist** component.

Basically a I get a table of **Players** and every Player has one or more **roles** (like forward, goalkeeper,ecc...). 
When I display my table, I would like to see in the roles column all the roles checked. How can  provide checked option dinamically for every player? I tried to work with the '**value**' attribute but I receive always **Empty list**.

This is the reference example:

```
<a href="#" id="options" data-type="checklist" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select options"></a>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#options').editable({
value: [2, 3],
source: [
{value: 1, text: 'option1'},
{value: 2, text: 'option2'},
{value: 3, text: 'option3'}
]
});
});
</script>
```

Basically I will need to substitute value attribute with a function like this:

```
...
value: function(){....},
....
```

Could someone help me to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.